# Automatically fill user credentials in another website

Tags: joomla

I have a URL "www.anothersite.com/login" in "www.mysite.com". When a visitor clicks the URL, it should go to "www.anothersite.com/login"'s login page and should automatically fill the "username" and "password" field which i give in backend script. Hence the user should just click "Login" button.
I tried using cURL, but no use. It just redirects to "www.anothersite.com/login" page but not filling credential fields and not even autofocussing the field.
Or If there's any joomla plugin to perform this action please post it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is Cross-Site scripting and is **FORBIDDEN**.

You can not run a script on a page you don't control because you could steal the user's username or password or other such bad things.  All modern browsers prevent this from happening.

This is the most obvious application of cross site scripting.  For more information on the clever and subtle ways in which attackers have historically tried to do such things, you should check out [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS)

The only other way I can think of supporting this functionality is if the site supported passing those parameters in a query string for the URL, but that would also be an extremely bad idea.

User's browsers can store this information if the user wishes to have things autofilled, and you should not be passing passwords back and forth after login.  You certainly should not be storing user credentials in such a way that they can be retrieved in their original form after the user has logged in.

Joomla won't store cleartext passwords by default, and for good reason.

If the external site supports delegation, you might be able to use OpenID or oauth.  There are plenty of examples of how to use those systems elsewhere on Stack Overflow, so you should read up on them.